# Failed prop type warning on Image component from react-native-expo-image-cache library

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently started using the Image component from the react-native-expo-image-cache library in my expo app as opposed to the the native Image component in react-native.

When I add the "preview" prop I get this warning:

"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`".

Here is what the component looks like:

```
const MyComponent = ({image}) => {
 <Image 
   style={styles.image}
   uri={image.full}
   preview={image.thumbnail}
   tint="dark"
 />
}
```

If I don't include the "preview" prop I don't get the warning. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Everything seems to work fine. I am able to get the progressive loading effect by using the preview prop, but I can't figure out why I'm getting this warning. I load images in a lot of different screens, so constantly getting this warning gets annoying pretty fast.

I am using:

- react-native-expo-image-cache version 4.1.0
- expo version 41

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: This error signifies that the `preview` or the `uri` prop does not have a correct image.. So just make sure your `uri` and `preview` should be correct.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by correct? Both the _uri_ and _preview_ props are urls that I am getting from cloudinary.com, as that is what I am using to store my images. I don't know why those urls would not be correct.

Comment: `console.log(image.full)` and `console.log(image.thumbnail)`. I think its undefined. Check once

Comment: When I console.log() I get the two urls for both the uri and the preview. When I copy/paste those urls in the browser it loads the expected images. And as I said, images are loading correctly in the app and the component is working as expected, however the warning still occurs.

Comment: At some pages there must be a `image.full` or `image.thumbnail` which is not a valid image file... That's why this warning. Go through your code once.